# Dynamically generating an exam based on data in an external file in ASP/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv

I wasn't sure how to phrase the initial question, but here's the short version of what I'm trying to do. And I don't want an answer in how to fix an issue per-say, more along the lines of I don't know best practices or what I should be using versus what I could be using.

I'm wanting to have a small web app, that takes in data from a csv file, parses it for a series of questions and answers, displays the questions and possible answers, and once everything is answered can check the answers against data in the csv file.

While I've worked with C# plenty in the past, it's been mostly back-end code and game logic. The times when a UI was involved, I knew while writing the code what the UI would entail.

I've had no problem grabbing the csv and parsing it for the data I need. I've got no problem displaying the data on the page for the most part. But I'm not sure the best method for displaying the information nor how to properly use it.

My initial thought, which I took and ran with, was to dynamically generate (using codebehind) what I would normally hard code. And so far that has been running a for loop that iterates through the csv for each question, generates a div with a new LiteralControl and fills the div with some Labels that have their text set to the contents of the csv file.

The issue with this is that I can only think of 2 ways to process the information after the fact, and I have no clue where to go from that point with either way.

My first thought was to add a submit button at the bottom of the page that would check each answer, but I'm not sure how to test each answer when the page is blank until runtime. I don't know of a way to dynamically assign variables using LiteralControls.

The other option I thought of was to add a submit button to each question and basically using show/hide to let the user answer each question one at a time, but at that point I don't know how to handle the click even for a button created at runtime, especially when I am creating a new button for each iteration of the for loop.

TL;DR: Wanting to create a webpage that generates an exam based on a csv file, and I don't know how to do anything other than parse the file for the information.

The idea is that you can alter the exam with the csv without touching the code.

Comment: This site is for specific coding questions, this is way too broad a question for SO...

Comment: There are lots of ways to do that; but as it stands your question is pretty broad. I recommend you start trying, ask specific questions here when you get stuck.

Comment: (also, you should put the `TL;DR` section at the top, since people who feel it's too long to read will never see that... :)

Comment: You could create a user control for your questions, it allows for an easier interaction ;) But as suggested, your question can be solved in many ways (eg, webservices to interact with the aspx with some javascript), reading the data using `Request.Form["name-of-control"]`, pick one, investigate, try and in case of problems, then come back to ask your question ;)